# How to set up Cluster/Grid computer(s)

Tags: cluster-computing, grid-computing

I have three computers,and I was wondering how I could go about clustering them together so I have a single computer (main) that has extra computing power. I would like to do this in windows (if applicable) for (main) over a home network with the ability to expand as I come across other computers.

(1 main) Intel Dual core 1.86 GHz 3 GB Ram (32 bit) ~300 GB HDD (Win 7)
(2) AMD 2.1 GHz Single core 3 GB ram (64 bit) ~300 HDD (Win 7)
(3) AMD 1.8 GHz Single core 256 Mb ram. (32 bit?) 40 GB HDD (W2K or XP. Trying to decide as of right now.)

Thanks for giving this a once over, and any advice.

Comment: And yes I am speaking of something like a Beowulf set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that very much depends on the kind of application you want to run on your cluster - its not clear from your question. If you want to be able to run seti@home stuff, then you don't need much more than a network connection. If you want to run programs that specifically support parallelism (such as some ray tracers) then they'll sometimes have their own parallelism layer (such as MPI) which will require a network connection and sometimes a shared file system. If you're running mainly windows desktop applications, then its unclear to me how you can use them in a clustered configuration - you could set up remote access on each one so that you can connect to each from a single console and run different applications on each one.

A classic 'beowulf' configuration would probably have MPI and a shared filesystem.

Comment: Well, I am running seti@home on two of them. But it's more or less just the fact that I've been wondering how to go about doing so (putting these computers I have laying around) and get some serious computing power.

Comment: what applications do you want to run? things that exist already or things you've written/will write yourself?

Comment: You know, I'm not 100% what I want to run/ realistically use it for. I'd like to set up a grid/ cluster to see what I could run (processing wise) with these computers that come in my possession.